# How do I move a spreadsheet from the root to my active folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I use the following code to create a new spreadsheet.

```
function addNewSpreadsheetWithFolderShift()
{
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var SSID=source.getId();
var fileInDocs = DocsList.getFileById(SSID);
var folder=fileInDocs.getParents()[0];
var folderName = folder.getName();
var folderID = folder.getId();
var TimeZone=Session.getTimeZone();
var DTStamp= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TimeZone, 'yyyy:MM:dd  HH:mm:ss  zzz');
var User=Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var output_name=DTStamp+"LineChecks"
var ssOut = SpreadsheetApp.create(output_name);  // Create a new spreadsheet, output_name.
ssOut.addToFolder(folder);
}
```

It winds up in my root directory.  I would like it to wind up in the directory I started from.  I tried using addToFolder but it seems that only files can be moved using it.  Is there some way to move the newly created spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DocsList service to move your file after its creation, try like this :

```
  ...
  var ssOut = SpreadsheetApp.create(output_name);  // Create a new spreadsheet, output_name.
  var root = DocsList.getRootFolder();
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById('your folder Id');// or use getFolderByName if you want
  var ssOutId = ssOut.getId();
  var newFile = DocsList.getFileById(ssOutId); // begin the 'move to folder process'
  newFile.addToFolder(folder);
  newFile.removeFromFolder(root);// had to do it in 2 separate steps 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is 2 years old I thought I would post an updated solution since DocsList has been deprecated. I was trying to figure out the same issue and came across this answer using [DriveApp.](http://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders)